# Why $\int_0^1 \frac d {dt}(t f(z^*+t(z-z^*))dt = f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I do not understand two parts in the following proof.

Let $O \subset \mathbb{C}$ open and and star-shaped, $f \in C^1(O, \mathbb C)$ holomorphic. Then $f$ has an antiderivative.

Proof: Let $z^*$ the "middle point" of the star-shape. Then set $F(z) = \int_0^1 f(z^*+t(z-z^*))(z-z^*)dt$. Then we get $$F'(z)=\int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial z}(f(z^*+t(z-z^*))(z-z^*))dt =$$
$$\int_0^1f(z^*+t(z-z^*))+f'(z^*+t(z-z^*))t(z-z^*)dt =$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac d {dt}(t f(z^*+t(z-z^*))dt = f(z)$$

I do not understand the end: Why does this equal $f(z)$?
And also, why can we pull the $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ into the integral at the beginning?

Comment: fundamental theorem of calculus. evaluate the integrand at t=1 and subtract at t=0 for your first question. for your next question, google Leibniz’s integral rule.